# How to pass value from TableView to Detail View Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to pass value from TableView to Detail View Controller? Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

The tableView delegate would do that when it gets the message that a row in the tableView has been selected.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to explore Flyingdiver's answer.

1. Fill your data in an array and then load table from that array. Make sure array is a class level object(Accessible at class level till class that contains table view is living).
2. When you will click on table, tableViewDelegate will call didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.
   there you will get indexPath(both Row and Section) for the cell which was clicked. Map those index path to your data array.
3. Now in detail view controller take a property data with suitable data type.
4. in  didSelectRowAtindexpath alloc object of detail View Controller assign data in property and push or present it on table.
   -> data can be a simple key based on which you can fetch data from db or INTERNET, Or it can be a data structure containing detailed data.

Hope above helps.....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to select a row which pushes you onto a `DetailViewController`, try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
  DetailViewController * detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
  // Set up any of the properties of your DetailViewController here. This is where the indexPath
  // comes in handy, as you can look up your array that you used to fill in your cells!
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:animated];
  [DetailViewController release];
}
```

Hope that Helps!